# Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul large file upload

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm using Spring Boot for a project and i'm trying to upload large files but somehow it doesnt work.

I have Spring Boot + Zuul (@EnableZuulProxy) running on port 8080 and then another microservice (Lets call it datastore) that should handle the upload.

I post a multipart request to http://localhost:8080/zuul/my/upload/endpoint which contains a file and a text string.

When I upload a file of 100MB everything works fine. Zuul passes the request to the datastore and the request comes in and is stored. 
But when I try to upload a larger file (150MB) Zuul processes the request and passes it to the datastore but then somewhere one of the multipart parameters is stripped from the request and then the datastore error returns a 400 and says 'Required request part 'string' is not present'.

I have the following configuration in both microservice (zuul and datastore)

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 1000MB
      max-request-size: 1000MB
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? I've tried adding the CommonsMultipartResolver but that didn't change anything.

Comment: which version of Spring-boot you are using?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of **`servlet`**, you should use **`http`**.

In my Zuul `application.yml` following properties work:

```
spring:
  http:  
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 1000MB
      max-request-size: 1000MB
```

In Spring boot 2 following properties work:

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 1000MB
      max-request-size: 1000MB
```

Here the properties are explained:

```
{
   "name": "spring.http.multipart.max-file-size",
   "type": "java.lang.String",
   "description": "Max file size. Values can use the suffixes \"MB\" or \"KB\" to indicate megabytes or\n kilobytes respectively.",
   "sourceType": 
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartProperties",
   "defaultValue": "1MB"
},
{
   "name": "spring.http.multipart.max-request-size",
   "type": "java.lang.String",
   "description": "Max request size. Values can use the suffixes \"MB\" or \"KB\" to indicate megabytes or\n kilobytes respectively.",
   "sourceType": 
   "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartProperties",
   "defaultValue": "10MB"
},
```

Comment: This answers could benefit by some more explanations and possibly some reformatting.

Comment: From Spring-Boot 2.0 `spring.http` is changes to `spring.servlet`.

Comment: Yes, i added my answer just now ;)